# header file in iOS 8 embedded frameworks

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, frameworks

I'm trying to create an embedded framework for use with iOS8. After creating one called SampleKit (BTW; is there any convention here, should I used a prefix?), it contains a header file that is puzzling me:

```
//! Project version number for SampleKit.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT double SampleKitVersionNumber;

//! Project version string for SampleKit.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT const unsigned char SampleKitVersionString[];
```

I know that `FOUNDATION_EXPORT` is a macro for `extern` or `extern "C"`, but I'm not sure about the two constants. Where am I supposed to set the value for them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Project > Build Settings > Versioning > Current Project Version :

[image]